# How to published moodle to Azure web app

Tags: php, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment, moodle

I successfully installed moodle in my local host and did some changes add some plugins, here my question is how can i publish this change to moodle azure web app, could you please give your suggest and guide me thanks,

Comment: You can follow instructions on [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-continous-deployment/) to setup continuous deployment for your web app.

Comment: @AaronChen-MSFT  My web app is php based, then how can i implement in Visual studio, I m using moodle (LMS)

Comment: If you are using Git as SCM, [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-php-get-started) is for you.